# Location based httpRuntime executionTimeout is not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, c#-4.0, httpruntime

I have one page for that I need to increase the execution timeout. 
so for that, i have set below code in web.config. but it's not working.

```
<location path="~/Admin/AdminControlPanel.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="204800" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If I set the same executionTimeout for global then it's working.

So Can anyone guide me why it's not working page specific? I want to do it only on one page.